# Properties of a set in $\ell^2$ space

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, compactness, lp-spaces

Let $\ell^2 = \{x= (x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots): x_n\in \mathbb C\text{ and } \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2 < \infty\}$

and $e_n \in \ell^2 $ be the sequence whose $n$-th element is $1$ and all other elements are $0$.

Equip the space with $\ell_2$ with the norm $$\|x\| = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Then the set $S=\{e_n : n \geq 1\}$  is

1. closed;
2. bounded;
3. compact;
4. and the sequence $s=(e_n)_{n\geq 1}$ contains a convergent sub-sequence.

Comment: $l^2$ is fine too!There was no need to edit it to $l_2$!

Comment: Just to clarify... by $S$ do you mean the space spanned by $S$? Or do you mean the *set* $S$

Comment: @Mathmo123 :Thanks... corrected it!

Comment: @Manasi: By the way Latex provides the extra (and I think very beautiful) special character little Lebesgue '$\ell$' (\ell) in contrast to the caligraphic letter '$\mathcal{l}$'...

Answer (score 2):

My answer: only 2 is true.
It is not closed as $\lim e_n$ does not exist. 
It is bounded as $||e_n||=1$
It is not compact as one can not find a finite sub-cover containing S. 
Neither does it contain a convergent subsequence as $\lim e_{n_k} $ does not exist.

Comment: Almost. $\lim e_n$ does not exist in $\ell_2$ either - so in fact $S$ *is* closed as it contains all it's limit points. I'm unconvinced by your explanation that it isn't compact - you need to find an open cover that has no finite sub cover explicitly.

Comment: You mean that as there no limit points, so it vacuously contains its limit points so S is closed! For the open cover, consider balls around each $e_n$ of radius 4 and take their union. No finite sub-cover will cover all $e_n$. Is this fine?

Comment: That's exactly right on both parts. For the compactness, whilst your answer certainly works, I think you'd be better considering balls of radius $\frac13$ as that way, no sub cover at all will cover $S$ and that is easier to prove

Answer (score 2):

Every pair of orthonormal vectors $e_i\neq e_j$ has distance precisely $d(e_i,e_j)=\sqrt{2}$.

So $S$ is closed as it contains only isolated points, it is bounded as all its elements have norm one, it is not compact as it contains infinitely many isolated points, it contains a convergent subsequence the constant ones?!

Comment: S is closed as there are no limit points and only isolated points as you correctly observed. Maybe you mean that S is bounded as all its elements have norm one but it is not compact. Look at the comments to my solution above: You construct an open cover by taking open balls around each $e_i$ of radius 1/4(say). None of these balls intersect. When you take finitely many balls, there is always an $e_i$ that is excluded. You can find this by considering the finite sub-cover, say ${e_s, e_p,... , e_r}$. Let $t = max[s,p,..r]$. Consider $ e_(t+1)$ which is not contained in any ball.

Comment: There is no convergent subsequence. There are no constant ones. You can only speak of convergence in $(a_{n_i},b_{n_i},....)$ if the sequence in each ordinate converges. $0s$ will never converge to a one. Now $lim e_{n_i}$ does not exist.

Comment: @Manasi: That was a typo (bounded rather than compact) but if you would have continued reading you might have noticed that I also answered compactness...

Comment: @Manasi: What is your question on subsequences *precisely*? You only asked for *a* convergent subsequence; so consider the constant sequence $(e_2,e_2,\ldots)$ then itself as a subsequence is convergent as well as all of its subsequences... Please clarify your question!

Comment: My last reply was based on your previous reply(before edition). Okay, it only has isolated points but as pointed out above you need to give an open cover for those isolated points and explain why you can not get a finite sub-cover- for compactness. I am afraid that I really do not get your constant sequence! Why is it constant? Is it an element of S? Here, we discuss  the possibility or impossibility of the convergent (sub)sequence of S. I do not think that you follow the question.

Comment: @Manasi: Do you consider $S$ as a set or a sequence? A set as it is not the same as a sequence misses the concept of subsequences... Manas, I think it is in your interest to clarify your concern - and I do follow your question.

Comment: S is a set ofcourse! If you construct any sequence from the elements of S, $<e_i>$,then it is not possible to obtain a convergent subsequence.

Comment: This is not a constant sequence-  < (1,0,0,....), (0,1,0,0....),(0,0,1,0,....),.....,(0,0,...0,1(n-th place),0,0,....),.....> Each term in this sequence is different from the other, so it can never be a constant sequence.

Comment: I have explained in my comments above as to why a convergent subsequence is impossible.

Comment: Well then you should say so - it's missing in your question. And well yes it is possible! Take the constant sequence $<e_2,e_2,...>$ that is made out of elements of $S$ and is indeed convergent!

Comment: @Manasi: As another situation consider the unit interval of real numbers $S=[0,1]$. Would you claim that though $<1,0.7,0.43,0.55,0.89,...>$ is a sequence in $S$, but $<1,1,1,...>$ is not a sequence in $S$?

Comment: A sequence is given by the function $f:N \to R$. Here, $f(1) = e_1 , f(2) = e_2, f(3) = e_3 ,.....$ so you see that in this case, it can not be $f(i) = e_2$. A subsequence is constructed from the given sequence.

Comment: For your next two statements, it depends on how you define the sequence and not on what interval you take. Why do you define a sequence and ask me whether you could consider that or not... for my problem, you are given a sequence by the set S,  $e_k :1 \leq k \leq infinity$ from there you consider subsequences $e_{i_k}$. Every convergent sequence is Cauchy. Can you construct a Cauchy sequence from $e_i$s?

Comment: Okay I should not assume the set S to be a sequence! The last option does not make any sense. It should not be left untouched.

Comment: Ok, you are really missunderstanding something: Sequences and sets are really not the same. Either you say $S$ is a set or a sequence but never never both simultaneously. If you say $S$ is a sequence thats fine but than concepts as closedness, boundedness and compactness are not defined by the sequence but by its image. That is important! If you however consider $S$ as a set theeeeeeennnn it is **NOT** a sequence but contains many many sequences like the constant ones or for example the one of many you're having in mind!

Comment: This distinction is really important: Consider for example an infinite countable set of numbers you want to add up. Then the sum will not contain repeating summands whereas adding up a sequence of numbers can have repeating summands. So you see the distinction of sets and sequences is really not just a technicality about range image and so on...

Comment: Uh no! I did not misunderstand sequences and sets! What I meant was that here I contructed a sequence from S by taking all $e_i$s which had order which I should not have done.

Comment: But as I said you should clarify what you want as it is written now it doesn't make sense yet...

Comment: @Manasi: By the way I'm sorry for that long discussion - your question all in all is very nice - go ahead like this ;)

Comment: Thank You. This was a multiple choice question in an exam. I guess it was the questioner's intent that one should only tick the correct options and leave out the incorrect ones. I guess that the last option could have been deliberate error! (I guess that points would be awarded on leaving it blank - set S contains a convergent subsequence).